# The url from an image via custom field (wordpress)

Tags: image, wordpress, field

Am not even sure if this can be done but...

Ive added a feed from my forums to wordpress it works great but I need it to auto add the url of the image in a custom field from the images in the post (feed) first image would be fine as its only ahve a slider

Is there any way to do this?

***Details***

Ok I think I did not explain this very well so made a few screen shots

[image]

This is my slider at the minute with my 
[image]

This is an imported post one other feed I was using

[image]

On this image you can see the custom field (which I have to fill in after every import)

[image]

Adding the image url into the custom field

[image]

and finaly a view of the slider working

This is what am trying to do (auto) so my feed from my booru / forums / 2 other of my sites and (2 other peoples) sites make my home page on a new site

Hope this explain it alot more

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to tackle this problem, but we'll need more information. Can you try explaining the issue a bit more thoroughly?

Comment: Hi many many thanks for at least replying ive been searching for the last 6 hours none stop...

Comment: I have a image slider I use which I have to add the image url(not the thumb url) all the time in a custom field (postimage) I have set up a rss feed going in to wordpress from my booru http://animelon.com/booru/

It works fine but I need a way to get it to auto add the image url in this custom field

Comment: Tell me if I have this right. There is some RSS feed that you link to your WP blog. This feed presumably contains images. You want the image from the newest RSS news item to be automatically added as a custom field to a particular post. Is this correct? If not, can you break this down, in extreme detail, so I might be able to assist.

Comment: That is correct (other than I have a custom field already "postimage" this is the only way I can get it to show in my slider and random places in the theme, I was adding the image url in this all the time)

If you need more detail I can try and explain it some more sorry its hard to explain as I don't quite understand it

Thanks again

Comment: So you are uploading the image to WordPress then copy and pasting the url to the custom field?  My plugin just gets the url from the feed and adds it to the custom field but I see the name of the custom field should be postimage.  This wont save the image in your database just the url to the image.

Comment: Not quite the image is in the feed already. am just adding it into my slider "postimage custom field" so it makes all the thumbs and adds the image into the slider

Comment: If you would like I could give you a temp login to my dev site so you can see first hand email me on vodkaholic27@live.co.uk (if you want to that is) would like to add also thanks alot for helping me Ive tryed everwhere to get some help on this.

Answer (score 2):

This uses the external [Simple Pie library built into WordPress](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/get_image_url) to fetch the feed, get the image url and create a new post for each item and save the image url as a custom field.

To activate the process we have to hook into wp_cron.  The code below does it daily but it would probably be better to do it weekly to prevent overlap.  Some overlap will probably occur so this still needs a way to check if we have already imported the image

First we need a function to save the custom field after the post has been created.  This section comes from [another answer I found on WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8569/wp-insert-post-php-function-and-custom-fields).

### Edit:

This needs to be wrapped in a plugin to schedule the cron event and the cron event was missing the action to make it fire.

### Edit:

Final version below tested and it works but the feed the OP is getting is using relative url's so the domain name needs to be added somewhere in the output code.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Fetch The Feed Image
Version: 0.1
Plugin URI: http://c3mdigital.com       
Description: Sample plugin code to fetch feed image from rss and save it in a post
Author: Chris Olbekson
Author URI: http://c3mdigital.com
License: Unlicense For more information, please refer to <http://unlicense.org/>
*/

//Register the cron event on plugin activation and remove it on deactivation
    
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'c3m_activation_hook');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'c3m_deactivation_hook');

add_action( 'c3m_scheduled_event', 'create_rss_feed_image_post');
function c3m_activation_hook() {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'weekly', 'c3m_scheduled_event');
}

function c3m_deactivation_hook() {
 wp_clear_scheduled_hook('c3m_scheduled_event');    
}


function create_rss_feed_image_post() {
     if(function_exists('fetch_feed')) {
            include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');               // include the required file
            $feed = fetch_feed('http://animelon.com/booru/rss/images'); // specify the source feed
        
    }       
    
        foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item) :
                        
        //  global $user_ID;
            $new_post = array(
            'post_title' =>  $item->get_title(),
            'post_status' => 'published',
            'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            //'post_author' => $user_ID,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_category' => array(0)
            );
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
            
        if ($enclosure = $item->get_enclosure() )
    
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'feed_image_url', $enclosure->get_link() );
        endforeach;
    }
```

Comment: Chris...this is mostly right, but I think there needs to an intermediary action to make this work. For instance, you should have `add_action('init_feed_cron', 'create_rss_feed_image_post');` and change `wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'create_rss_feed_image_post');` to `wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'init_feed_cron');`. Not sure why, but you cannot call the function directly. In `wp_schedule_event`, you call the action, which calls the function. Also note that this code will only run if you put it in a plugin and activate it after the code is in there.

Comment: Ok I tested it and it worked with some minor adjustments to the Simple Pie loop to get the image url.  I've update the code above.

Comment: Hi many thanks I'll try this abit later after ive took my lad to school, I was using FeedWordPress to import the feed but if this works right I'll get rid of feedwordpress thanks again

Comment: Ive added some more info (because I think I am explaining it wrong) Thanks